# Unable to upload large files using nodejs/axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I am writing a nodejs client that would upload files (files can be both binary or text files) from my local dev machine to my server which is written in Java, configuring which is not an option. I am using the following code to upload files, it works fine for files upto 2 gb, but beyond that it throws an error mentioned below. Now you may think that the server might not be allowing files more than 2 gb but I have successfully uploaded files upto 10 gb using Rest clients like Postman and Insomnia on the same instance.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const axios = require("axios");
const FormData = require("form-data");

function uploadAxios({ filePath }) {
  
let formData;
try {
  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("filedata", fs.createReadStream(filePath));
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}

  axios
    .post(
      `https://myinstance.com`,
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          ...formData.getHeaders(),
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          Authorization:
            "Basic xyz==",
        },
        maxContentLength: Infinity,
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        // maxContentLength: 21474836480,
        // maxBodyLength: 21474836480, // I have tried setting these values with both numbers and the keyword Infinity but nothing works
      }
    )
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
}

const filePath = "C:\\Users\\phantom007\\Documents\\BigFiles\\3gb.txt";
 
uploadAxios({  filePath  });
```

Error I get:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#

<--- Last few GCs --->
es[7844:0000023DC49CE190]    47061 ms: Mark-sweep 33.8 (41.8) -> 33.8 (41.8) MB, 417.2 / 0.1 ms  (+ 947.1 ms in 34029 steps since start of marking, biggest step 431.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 15184 ms) finalize incremental marking via stack guard[7844:0000023D
C49CE190]    48358 ms: Mark-sweep 34.4 (41.8) -> 31.8 (40.5) MB, 1048.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 1049 ms) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old spac

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000002E294C255E9 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: new ArrayBuffer(aka ArrayBuffer)(this=0000022FFFF822D1 <undefined>,65536)

    1: _read [fs.js:~2078] [pc=0000004AD942D301](this=0000039E67337641 <ReadStream map = 000002F26D804989>,n=65536)
    2: read [_stream_readable.js:454] [bytecode=000002A16EB59689 offset=357](this=0000039E67337641 <ReadStream map = 000002F26D804989>,n=0)
    3: push [_stream_readable.js:~201]...

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

It looks like the error is because it has exceed the memory limit, i know by passing the flag --max-old-space-size i can overcome this, but i want this to be scalable and not hardcode an upper limit.

PS: My dev machine has 12 GB free memory

Edit: I added the error trace.

Comment: Did you log where it fails, i.e. is it formData.append, formData.getHeaders() or axios.post?

Comment: I can post a 4GB file to a local Express / Multer server with your code. It doesn't seem to make any difference whether I use a limit of 21474836480 or Infinity. Both work, so there must be something else causing the issue. Have you tried changing the timeout? e.g. timeout: xxx, it's a bit of a longshot tho!

Comment: @Pavlo You were right, i wrapped the formData in try catch and got the error (i have edited my post and added the error).

Comment: @TerryLennox I have got the error and pasted it in my original post. It seems to be an out of memory issue. And now i want it to be scalable i.e. not fix an upper memory limit. Please suggest

Comment: Well that narrows things down a lot. I'll try to reproduce the error!

Comment: I can reproduce the error, albeit with a larger file ~13GB. I can see the process memory going nuts... now for a resolution!

Comment: @TerryLennox It probably took you 13gb to reproduce the error because you might have more free memory in your dev machine than mine. So i am assuming that the entire 13 GB file is getting dumpted into the memory before it is sending for upload, but isnt that what createReadStream is meant for?

 Also, if I use CURL from command line, i can still upload a file of 10 GB.

Comment: You can do a multipart/chunked file upload in node, reading data using a read stream which uses a lot less resources

Comment: That curl command you asked me to send is failing:  0curl: (7) Failed to connect to instance.com port 443: Connection refused.

Comment: @TerryLennox Yes instance.com is a fictitious url, i was looking for how to call that curl command from my nodejs app, so asked your help.

Comment: Ah yes, I assumed that was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using multer to define limit, see next code:

```
  app.use(multer({
  storage: storage,
  dest: path.join(pathApp),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5000000
  },
  fileFilter: function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    var filetypes = /json/;
    var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname));

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      console.log("Port ".concat(app.get('port')) + " - Uploading file " + file.originalname);
      return cb(null, true, req);
    }

    cb(JSON.stringify({
      "success": false,
      "payload": {
        "app": "upload",
        "function": "upload"
      },
      "error": {
        "code": 415,
        "message": 'File type not valid'
      }
    }));
  }
}).single('file1'));
```